# spark-shell load scala config using typesafe config

Tags: scala, apache-spark, typesafe-config

I am trying to load `application.conf` in spark-shell using typesafe-config.

Following is the code and spark-shell command:

**scala code:**

```
import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory}

val config: Config = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf")
val env = config.getString("key.key1")
```

**spark-shell commands**:

- `spark-shell --jars confing-1.3.4.jar  --files application.conf --driver-java-options -Dconfig.file=application.conf` (attempt 1)
- `spark-shell --jars confing-1.3.4.jar (attempt 2)`

**application.conf:**

```
key {

 key1 = "value1"

}
```

**error:**

```
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: system properties: No configuration setting found for key 'key'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Submit an application property file with Spark typesafe config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53290715/submit-an-application-property-file-with-spark-typesafe-config)

Answer (score 0):

Where is your conf file present? Did you try using the full path from the root?
Eg:

```
val config: Config = ConfigFactory.load("/<root-path>/application.conf")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass file to each executors by `--files "application.conf"` and  read with `ConfigFactory.parseFile()` as

You can get the file passed by `--files` with `SparkFiles.get`

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import java.io.File
import org.apache.spark.SparkFiles

val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(SparkFiles.get("application.conf")))
```

This should load the config you want.

Comment: Thanks, @Shankar. this is taking application.conf path to /tmp..... location in hdfs which doesn't exist. It returns an error "path does not exist"